# ImmSetConversionStatus return TRUE, but IME not toggled

Tags: c++, windows

I'm Korean.
And I test the program using

```
{
  OnSetFocusEditCode
  {
    if(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_CODE)->GetSafeHwnd() == GetFocus()->GetSafeHwnd())
    {
        HIMC himc = ImmGetContext(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_NAME)->GetSafeHwnd());
        ImmSetConversionStatus(himc, IME_CMODE_HANGEUL, IME_SMODE_CONVERSATION);
        ImmReleaseContext(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_NAME)->GetSafeHwnd(), himc);
    }
  }
}
```

It's completely done when it's running from Desktop parent.
But we have solution to restart this program, it named ~~svchost, it has SYSTEM authority, and it is a service program.

So, When our program starts from this service program, ImmSetConversionStatus return TRUE, but IME not toggled at first.
And I changed the focus(by mouse), and set the focus in first editbox (by mouse), it works.

I coded the setfocus in the code, but it doesn't work.
Please would you let me get your solution?

I googled half day yesterday, but I haven't found the solution.

Comment: I resolved, use keybd_event(VK_HANGUL,0,0,0) before DoModal();

Comment: in Windows 8, not worked, so set Timer, and when you can get focus, call set focus, kill timer